# Delete Github OAuth access token when user logged out of GitHub

Tags: github, oauth, passport.js, github-api, passport-github2

I'm building a website which uses GitHub OAuth to authorise users. I'm successfully authorising users and able to get `access_token` from GitHub to talk to their API. When user logs out of my app I invalidate the session and delete the authorisation, but when user stays active in my app and logs out of GitHub, the `access_token` is still active [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759513/about-github-oauth-authentication/18790394#18790394).

I'm looking for a way to logout / re-authorise users when they have logged out of GitHub.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#delete-an-authorization

Comment: @jwilleke Thanks for your answer, I'm calling this api when user logs out of my app. I looking for a mechanism where I'll notified somehow when user logged out of GitHub so that I can call the api mentioned by you so that I can delete the authorisation.

Comment: @UdayVishwakarma I'm looking the same thing. I built a site that uses github api extensively. Did you ever find a github api endpoint that accomplished this?